# Get Twitter screen name from "oauth_token" and "oauth_token_secret"

Tags: api, oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have the "oauth_token" and "oauth_token_secret" values stored in the database. Is it possible to retrieve the twitter account's user name from just these two values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with this REST method : `GET https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json` (or `.xml` if you prefer XML results instead of JSON). It is an authenticated request, so you will pass the `oauth_token`in the `Authorization` header as usual. If the request is successful, it will return you the 200 OK HTTP code with the corresponding user. Otherwise it will return a 401 return code. The Twitter application used for the request has to authorized by the user of course.